# What can replace IN Clause in query to make it faster?

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

I want to get all records from oracle which have the same `MANUF_PART` and `MATERIAL`. I group column `MANUF_PART` and `MATERIAL` first and check for duplication using `COUNT`.

```
SELECT MANUF_PART , COUNT(MANUF_PART), MATERIAL, COUNT(MATERIAL) 
FROM (
    SELECT * 
    FROM IR_MPN 
    WHERE SCALE_QTY = MOQ
)
GROUP BY MANUF_PART, MATERIAL 
HAVING  COUNT(MANUF_PART) > 1 
AND COUNT(MATERIAL) > 1
```

After I get the result, what I want to do is:

```
Select * from table where MANUF_PART in (subquery) and MATERIAL in (subquery)
```

This is my query here and it's workable.

```
SELECT *
FROM IR_MPN
WHERE MANUF_PART IN
(
    SELECT MANUF_PART
    FROM
    (
        SELECT MANUF_PART, COUNT(MANUF_PART), MATERIAL, COUNT(MATERIAL)
        FROM
        (
            SELECT *
            FROM IR_MPN
            WHERE SCALE_QTY = MOQ
        )
        GROUP BY MANUF_PART, MATERIAL
        HAVING  COUNT(MANUF_PART) > 1 AND COUNT(MATERIAL) > 1
    )
)
AND MATERIAL IN
(
    SELECT MATERIAL
    FROM
    (
        SELECT MANUF_PART, COUNT(MANUF_PART), MATERIAL, COUNT(MATERIAL)
        FROM
        (
            SELECT *
            FROM IR_MPN
            WHERE SCALE_QTY = MOQ
        )
        GROUP BY MANUF_PART, MATERIAL
        HAVING  COUNT(MANUF_PART) > 1 AND COUNT(MATERIAL) > 1
    )
)
AND SCALE_QTY != '0'
ORDER BY MANUF_PART
```

Now my problem is when I use this query for 60,000 records, it takes around 1 minute(slow) because I used 2 In clause in this query.
I had tried EXISTS (much faster) but it doesn't give me the result I want.

How can I make it faster?

Comment: You can add indexes on the table for fields used in the where, also checking subqueries adding indexes where necessary

Comment: Please show DDL and EXPLAIN - otherwise we're just guessing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest quick rewrite would be like this:

```
SELECT * FROM IR_MPN
WHERE (MANUF_PART,MATERIAL) IN
(
    SELECT MANUF_PART, MATERIAL
    FROM IR_MPN
    WHERE SCALE_QTY = MOQ
    GROUP BY MANUF_PART, MATERIAL
    HAVING COUNT(MANUF_PART) > 1 AND
           COUNT(MATERIAL) > 1
) AND 
SCALE_QTY != '0'
ORDER BY MANUF_PAR;
```

But the proper way is to use analytic functions.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT IR_MPN.*,
           COUNT(MANUF_PART) OVER (PARTITION BY MANUF_PART, MATERIAL) AS COUNT_MANUF_PART,
           COUNT(MATERIAL) OVER (PARTITION BY MANUF_PART, MATERIAL) AS COUNT_MATERIAL
    FROM IR_MPN
    WHERE SCALE_QTY = MOQ
)
WHERE COUNT_MANUF_PART>1 AND
      COUNT_MATERIAL>1 AND
      SCALE_QTY != '0';
```

Answer (score 0):

A `WITH` factoring clause, perhaps?

```
with dup as
  (select manuf_part,
          material,
          count(*)
   from ir_pmn
   where scale_qty = 'MOQ'
   group by manuf_part,
            material
   having count(*) > 1
  )
select *
from manuf_part t join dup d on d.manuf_part = t.manuf_part
                            and d.material   = t.material
where t.scale_qty <> '0'
order by t.manuf_part;
```

---

By the way, condition you wrote: `where t.scale_qty <> '0'`: looks like it is "quantity". Is quantity really a string? Shouldn't that be `<> 0`?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get all records from oracle which have the same MANUF_PART and MATERIAL.

If I understand correctly, you want an analytic function:

```
select m.*
from (select m.*, count(*) over (partition by manuf_part, material) as cnt
      from IR_MPN m
     ) m
where cnt >= 2
order by manuf_part, material;
```